# Is your own soulless clone a valid target for mind-swapping?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

If an appropriately preserved but soulless clone of oneself is available—probably created through the use of the spell [*clone*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#clone) but maybe generated some other way—is that body a valid target for the psionic powers [*mind seed*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-seed), [*mind switch*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-switch), [*true mind switch*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-switch-true), or similar effects?
The entity may or may not be the originator of the clone.

Comment: Can you offer an explanation as to *why* a creature would *want* to become itself *again*? (I can think of only medical reasons, and if that's it, that's cool, but reasons from your perspective might help give this question some heft.)

Comment: Several possibilities: age reset while keeping (most) original knowledge attempt, getting rid of something specific to the original body that isn't affecting the clone body, plot to perfectly disguise self as another person, plot to stage the murder of someone and prevent resurrection or speak with dead attempt, mess with the pcs minds without using a mirror of opposition, commit the perfect crime, the list goes on.

Answer (score 4):

## This Doesn't Work Directly

### [*Clone*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#clone) Grows a Body Without a Soul

> ...A duplicate can be grown while the original still lives, or when the original soul is unavailable, but the resulting body is merely a soulless bit of inert flesh, which rots if not preserved...

### [*Mind Seed*](http://www.dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-seed) Uses the Target's Soul

> ...Although the subject starts off with memories of your experiences, it possesses its original “soul” and physical body and is free to develop its own personality based on its own new experiences...

### [*Mind-switch*](http://www.dndsrd.net/psionicPowersGtoP.html#mind-switch) Targets a Living Creature

> You can attempt to take control of a nearby living creature, forcing your mind (and soul) into its body...

### [*Polymorph Any Object*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph-any-object) To the Rescue!

As with the [Psionic Sandwich](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1187.msg8798#msg8798), you can PAO the body from a corpse into a living creature, mind-switch, then dispel the PAO. PAO it into a [shrieker](http://www.dndsrd.net/monstersEtoF.html#fungus) or other immobile creature, first, then manifest [*dispel psionics*](http://www.dndsrd.net/psionicPowersDtoF.html#dispel-psionics), as per the sandwich (or merely wait, immobile, for 3 hours for the PAO to elapse). The clone now has your soul and mind in it now.

Even this might not be enough to animate the clone; the spell only refers to the original creature's soul, not adding in just *any* old soul. I'm unaware of anything that fixes this, but...

### [*Stone to Flesh*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#stone-to-flesh) Works Wonders

*Stone to flesh* sets precedent, which I'd say allows you to bring that there corpse to life.

Creating a corpse via *stone to flesh* is faster and cheaper, and actually talks about a life force being available to animate the created flesh. Consider just using it to make the body, in conjunction with [*stone shape*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#stone-shape) or [*fabricate*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#fabricate).

The best way I can think to do this is to *stone shape/fabricate* a beautiful statue, PAO it into that shrieker (it's a creature now), mind switch, dispel/wait, then you or a helper cast *stone to flesh*. Order matters here; your mind should be inside the stone *before* you make into flesh, as that's closest to StF's phrasing

> Such flesh is inert and lacking a vital life force **unless a life force** or magical energy is available...

[Spell to power Erudite](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070629a) can manifest Sor/Wiz spells, so can PAO, *fabricate/stone shape*, and *stone to flesh*. But he needs a way to Still or Silently cast them, if he's doing this to himself.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting to note the the mind and soul are not synonymous per the text of the clone effect. Also, the the clone does not seem to count as a living creature despite being something that grows and develops from the flesh sample to the full body.

Comment: @nijineko When a creature dies, its soul departs: "Death causes the
character’s soul to leave the body and journey to an Outer Plane" (*PH* 307). While it might be presumptuous to assume the inverse, it's not wholly out of line to postulate *soulless* equaling *not living*, making at least *mind switch* impossible to use on a traditional arcane clone. *Edit:* O, you spotted that, too, huh? `:-)`

Comment: Also, if the creature is dead, even for a few months, its soul can enter the clone (assuming free, able, and willing), whereupon it automatically becomes a living creature. It would seem that a soul is the difference between living and inert. Also note that *mind seed* targets a humanoid, not a creature. Just because it had no soul doesn't seem to matter. In the case of not having a soul in the first place, it would simply result in it not gaining a soul from the *mind seed* effect.

Comment: I also note that the mechanical text for mind switch says "you and one other creature" living only comes up in the descriptive text. Also, soul and mind go one way, but only mind goes the other. (Probably simply poor writing rather than intended mechanic). [Bonus points for linking Minmaxboards, btw]

Comment: Corpses aren't creatures, they're objects.

Comment: @Chemus [Only according to the FAQ.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan O...k. I wasn't parroting the FAQ, but perhaps I should have been clearer, rather than using shorthand. Clones without the original soul ready to inhabit the body "are soulless bits of inert flesh". Objects, by intent. They've never been alive, have no ability scores, etc., until they've been inhabited by a soul. nijineko, yep, mechanical table says you and one other creature. That other isn't descriptive text *per se*, but rules; The two sentences are describing in depth what targets are eligible, and which parts go. The lack of repetition re: (and soul) is just shorthand.

Comment: One wonders if elemental binding (or some similar effect) could provide enough of a soul for any of the questioned effects to function on the clone?